# What further steps do I need to allow my static site hosted on s3 to make https requests to my server on elastic beanstalk?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, https, axios, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My current stack is pretty simple:
Backend: Django 2.1.1, python 3.6 I am running it on elastic beanstalk with an application load balancer. I have port 80 listening for HTTP and port 443 listenin for HTTPS with my ssl certificate selected. I did not select an SSL policy as I have no idea what these do.

Frontend: React, mainly using axios to do requests (axios.get, axios.put, etc). I have this hosted on two s3 buckets, mainsite.com, where all my static files are, and www.mainsite.com, which redirects HTTP to that site. I also have 2 cloudfront distributions which redirect HTTP to HTTPs, using the same certificate as the one I used for my load balancer. I then created 2 record sets and set the alias to the cloud distribution. When I try to do any request, I see in the console:

```
xhr.js:173 Mixed Content: 
The page at 'https://fakesite.net/login' 
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 
'http://myenv-env.randomletters.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/rest-auth/login/'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

What else do I need to configure? Do I need to change code, or is it all aws related.

Comment: Redirection won't help because browser won't even try to access the http links, you need to change in your code and make them all https link.

Comment: I see. So if I just change my url from http://mysite-env.stuff.us-east-1.ellasticbeanstalk.com to https, that should resolve everything? I currently use axios but I'm not sure if theres an option to go a specific port or something.

Comment: You just need to make the reference of the url to (https)://mysite-env.stuff.us-east-1.ellasticbeanstalk.com and browser should not block this as mix content, of course you need to take care of two things, the link should actually wok on https, you won't have the cert for beanstalk so you need a custom domain and a cert for that domain, additionally take care of the CORS, boy, this indeed a lot of change.

Comment: I want to delete my first comment, changing https link of beakstalk would result in a cert error because you can't have a cert for elasticbeanstalk.com so you need a custom domain here.

Comment: What do you mean by custom domain? Does that have to do with creating a record set on route 53? So my updated situation is: I updated security groups for port 443 to allow 0.0.0.0 and ::/0, I changed the url to https, but now I get a connection time out error. I'm not sure what else I need to config.